# Store Document Library metadata into word document along with all previous version metadata in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement where user wants to save Library columns metadata into word document.This is quite simple with quick parts but user also wants to keep the old versions metadata details into the document.Whenever metadata gets changed it also updates the same detail into the document, but it will not keep the older metadata value here as it simply amends with the change.
For example: if document is having details of reviewer column value, it will not keep the previous reviewer name. It will just update the existing reviewer name with the new reviewer.How can i keep both reviewers name in the document.

Environment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion is that the correct answer is NO! They want a Word document because that is what they are familiar with, but that doesn't mean it is the correct tool for tracking metadata history. There are plenty of other reporting options that are better suited for this task.

THAT SAID...

This looks like a PowerShell problem to me. You can run a script that loads the SharePoint snapin, queries the metadata, then writes it to a word document. You could use PowerShell to grab an existing word document from SharePoint if it exists, adds the new information, and then updates the  the word document.

Comment: Thank you for sharing workarounds. My customer has changed the requirement a bit, now the file type is PDF.

Is it possible to keep Document Library metadata into PDF type files?